# Get min(id) and corresponding other fields along with joining original field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table e (ms sql) which has below structure and data for example-

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Id |  colx |  coly |  colz |  cola |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | x1    | y1    | z1    | a     |
|  2 | x2    | y2    | y2    | a     |
|  3 | x3    | y3    | z3    | a     |
|  4 | x4    | y4    | y4    | a     |
|  5 | x5    | y5    | z5    | b     |
|  6 | x6    | y6    | z6    | b     |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want the select query result where cola=a where colx and id should be coming from the min(id) for that group where cola=a and coly=colz.... Result -

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| RsId |  rscolx |  rscoly |  rscolz |  rscola |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    2 | x2      | y1      | z1      | a       |
|    2 | x2      | y2      | y2      | a       |
|    2 | x2      | y3      | z3      | a       |
|    2 | x2      | y4      | y4      | a       |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: is it `my sql` or `MSSQL` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions.  The following uses two steps ([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef3df/1)):

```
select t.*,
       min(case when id = min_id then colx end) over (partition by cola)
from (select t.*,
             min(case when coly = colz then id end) over (partition by cola) as min_id
      from t
      where cola = 'a'
     ) t;
```